# To access elements thats being dragged over using dragula (Ng2)

Tags: angular, dragula

Is it possible to access elements that's being dragged over, (not the dragula bag)?

Im using Ng2-Dragula.

Im currently using the built in functions, but there are no parameters for elements thats being hovered over except the bag.

```
this.dragulaService.over.subscribe((value:any) => {
     this.onOver(value);
});

private onOver(args:any) 
{
    let [bag, element, target, source, smth] = args;
}
```